# How to activate the STL import/export addon from the commandline?

Tags: add-on, command-line

From the commandline documentation, activating an addon should be:
`$: blender --addons <list of addons to activate>`

But I can't seem to find the right syntax.
Example with the STL import/export:

```
$: blender -b --addons io_mesh_stl
Exception in module register(): '/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 312, in enable
  mod.register()
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py", line 260, in register
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/utils.py", line 609, in register_module
    raise Exception("register_module(%r): defines no classes" % module)
Exception: register_module('io_mesh_stl'): defines no classes
```

Comment: @zeffi: Ho thx. Didn't expect that. You're right. 

Side note, I'm not well versed with Stack habits. In this case, should I delete the question, update it or what else?

Comment: don't delete the question, just be more specific in the title. that it pertains to the STL import addon. -- i'll elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl()` will be present without explicitly enabling the add-on. `io_mesh_stl` is enabled already by default, re-enabling it seems to be the problem here.

Exactly why you get that error is not something I'd spend much time on as a user, considering the fact that it can be avoided by not re-enabling the add-on.